# Best method for processing upload user images

Tags: php, image-processing, infrastructure

If one were to create a site where users could upload images in various formats (JPG, PDF, etc.) and process that image into one monochrome GIF copy and a PDF, what would be the best infrastructure for doing so?

I know that there is already a question about image processing infrastructure, but I would like to know what specific method would be recommended for PHP.

Should I script a PHP background job? Should I store the list of images to process in a database? Should the processing of the images take place in the uploading PHP script?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: the "best" solution will depend on image sizes and transaction volumes. please specify.

Comment: stillstanding: The average image size should be about that of an average person's scanner's resolution (600x600, or something like that) except in the size of a page. I doubt I can estimate transaction volumes at this point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to call an ImageMagick binary to do things to an image. And modern servers are more than fast enough to do it as part of the post-upload processing before returning the success page to the end-user. I work on a commercial site that does exactly that for user uploads and we've never had a problem.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks, I'll run some tests on this, then get back with a reply.

Comment: Alright, it seems to work perfectly fine! Thank all of you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the uploaded images into a filesystem, not database, and have an external/standalone component take care of the image processing. That component could be anything from a Java to Perl application, not necessarily php.

Comment: So you would opt for a long-running process in the background looking through the filesystem for images to process?

Comment: Yep. It decouples the uploading part from any processing of the images.